# Capture name of user who updated field

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I am trying to build out a formula field or flow to capture who made changes to a date field on the lead object.

The 'Last Modified by' field effectively does this, but does not distinguish what the last update was. It records the last update to any field on the record.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting up [Field History Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tracking_field_history.htm&type=5) on the field you want to track. This will show which user updated the field you are tracking.

If you need it in a field for reports, you could use a Flow or an Apex Trigger to do this. Whenever the date field is changed, store the running user in your custom field.

I would recommend following the Trailhead module on [Record Triggered Flows](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/record-triggered-flows) for this.

Comment: thanks, this is active but one cannot track this on a report, only on a record level. It only shows the "last modified by" for the last field update for any field.

Comment: in that case, you can use either a flow or apex trigger